# How can I get the decline reason by using Docusign API without "EnvelopeRecipients:: List"

Tags: docusignapi

I've been working with the DocuSign API for some time now, and it's all fine, but when the signer refuses to sign, I get a rejection message using "EnvelopeRecipients:: List".

However, frequent use of the API is prohibited in the go-Live instructions.What should I do?
[enter link description here](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/esign101/rules-and-limits/)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qti03.png)

```
 RecipientViewRequest viewOptions = new RecipientViewRequest
        {
            ReturnUrl = returnUrl,
            ClientUserId = this.CurrentUserID,//DSConfig.ClientID,
            AuthenticationMethod = "none",
            UserName = displayName,
            Email = userEmail
        };
        // Use the SDK to obtain a Recipient View URL
        var envelopesApi = GetEnvelopesApi();
        ViewUrl viewUrl = envelopesApi.CreateRecipientView(JwtAuthClient.JwtAuth.Account.AccountId, envelopeId, viewOptions);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use DocuSign Connect webhook or if you're using embedded signing, it's in the URL that goes back to your app after the user finished signing.
" frequent use of the API is prohibited" is not accurate. Polling is what is bad/not allowed. "frequent" is relative. If your app need to make more API calls - you may make more API calls. There are limits etc. but you don't want to also go overboard with the notion you cannot make API calls.

Comment: My app is a website.How to get DeclinedReason in Return Url?I didn't find the right method in the documentation.

Comment: do you use embedded signing?

Comment: yes,I fixed the question and added my code at the end of the question.

Comment: OK, I think I was wrong, you will not get the reason just the fact that it was declined. You will need to make another API call to find the reason.

Comment: If I use "EnvelopeRecipients:: List" frequently, I get the following error message when I use "GO-Live"."Excessive polling does not comply with DocuSign rules and limits."

Comment: you can use a different endpoint ,to get a single envelope

Answer (score 0):

You're facing limitation issues because of bad implementation.

I know it's too late but I recently work on DocuSign API and randomly found this question, that's why decide to answer it for other people if they come to this question to find the solution.

The Latest DocuSign API version is 2.1 and I'll only talk about that version.

In this version, either you call via SDK or your custom code [List API Call](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/envelopes/envelopes/liststatuschanges/)
end-point has many options which we can use to optimize the Envelope check status.

count, start_position, and continuation_token parameters are useful when you have a large number of envelopes on the Cloud which status do you want to check (include decline) to split the result in chunks or you can say page wise. It will help you to manage frequent call limitation issues like you can filter only those envelopes which status you want to check with further options and fetch envelopes in a bunch instead of each envelope status will help you to reduce the number of calls to DocuSign.
(I'm not going to train you on how you can write code as this is not a platform for that)

For the case which is mentioned in the question, the same API end-point will be useful to fetch only declined envelopes with messages.

Like for that purpose you just need to pass "declined" against the status parameter which is useful to filter cloud envelops status-wise. To include declined message with the response, you need to pass "recipients" against the "include" parameter, which appends the Recipient entity with each envelope object where you can filter out the declined message. "DeclinedReason" or "VoidedReason" there are two properties which can return a decline message with this call. If you want to see the complete schema of the envelope entity, you can go through same link [List API Call](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/envelopes/envelopes/liststatuschanges/)

In short, to solve the limitation issue you can use "listStatusChanges" end-point which has too many optional parameters which you can utilize as per your need but the performance depends on how you utilize it.

PS: Webhook is a better option to sync data between two services in optimize way or without any calling limitation, my answer is only for those who don't want to use webhook.